# Heat equation of a rod which has constant heat of $\theta$ at on one end and $\alpha$ at the other end

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I’m studying PDE and am currently on heat equation subject .
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=c^2 \frac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial x^2}$$

This book I’m reading worked on heat equation of a rod for different cases
But I’m interested in one case of scenario this book didn’t cover.

For example when this rod has temperature of $0$ at one end and $\theta$ at the other obviously we will have :
$$\lim u(x,t) =\frac{\theta}{L} x , t \rightarrow\infty $$

But What if the rod has constant heat of $\theta$ at on one end and $\alpha$ at the other end .
What would this $u(x,t)$ would be .
And obviously after some time the heat of each x will not change afterwards , and I really want to know how to calculate that $t$.

If you know the link for the proof i would be really interested and appreciated.

And even when i want to imagine the physical side of this scenario I cannot tell what would happen if $t \rightarrow\infty$

Comment: Basically you just have boundary conditions you need to adjust for. Go through the process of solving the heat equation but impose a boundary condition like $u(-L,t)=T_1 ~,~ u(L,t)=T_2$. I can detail this calculation in an answer if you run into problems.

Comment: @K.defaoite I would really appreciate if you could do that for $u(0,t)=T_1 , u(L,t)=T_2$. cause i tried to do so but couldnt proceed. if you have time that would be really kind of you to do.

Comment: Role? Do you mean *rod*?

Comment: @HansLundmark yup.sorry

Comment: @K.defaoite there is no need for that anymore. I figured it out. Thank you so much.

Comment: @negar I would suggest adding your solution as an answer and accepting your own answer to mark this query as resolved and for the benefit of possible future readers.